# Exercise 7.B, Norm of vectors, Elements of Real Analysis, Bartle(Pg 65)

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I would like someone to check if my proof to the below problem on norm properties in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ is correct.

> 7.B If $x=(\xi_{1},\xi_{2},\ldots,\xi_{p})$ is any element in $\mathbb{R}^p$, define
>
> $|x|_{1}=|\xi_{1}|+|\xi_{2}|+\ldots+|\xi_{p}|$.
>
> Prove that the function $f(x)=|x|_{1}$ satisfies all of the norm properties, but it does not satisfy the parallelogram identity.

**Proof.**

Property 1.

$|x|\ge{0}$.

It is plain(evident) that $|x|_{1}\ge0$ is true, since all $x_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$.

Property 2.

$|x|=0$ iff $x=\theta$, the zero-vector.

It is plain that $|x|_{1}=0$ if and only if all $x_{i}=0$.

Property 3.

$|cx|=|c||x|$

We need to prove that $|cx|_{1}=|c||x|_{1}$

$\begin{align}|cx|_{1}&=|cx_{1}|+|cx_{2}|+\ldots+|cx_{p}|\\
&=|c||x_{1}|+|c||x_{2}|+\ldots+|c||x_{p}|\\
&=|c|(|x_{1}|+|x_{2}|+\ldots+|x_{p}|)\\
&=|c||x|_{1}\end{align}$

Property 4. $|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$

We need to prove that, $|x+y|_{1}\le|x|_{1}+|y|_{1}$

We have,

$\begin{align}
|x+y|_{1}&=|x_{1}+y_{1}|+|x_{2}+y_{2}|+\ldots+|x_{p}+y_{p}|\\
&\le|x_{1}|+|y_{1}|+|x_{2}|+|y_{2}|+\ldots+|x_{p}|+|y_{p}|\text{ since } |a+b|\le|a|+|b|\space{a,b}\in\mathbb{R}\\
&=|x_{1}|+|x_{2}|+\ldots+|x_{p}|+|y_{1}|+|y_{2}|+\ldots+|y_{p}|\\
&=|x|_{1}+|y|_{1}
\end{align}$

Therefore, it follows that $|x+y|_{1}\le|x|_{1}+|y|_{1}$.

*Is there a better way to prove property (4)?*

*I believe, with $f(x)=|x|_{1}$ defined the way it is in this problem, we cannot express $x\cdot{x}=|x|^{2}_{1}$*

Also, how do I prove that the parallelogram identity $|x+y|^{2}+|x-y|^2=2\{|x|^{2}+|y|^{2}\}$ does not hold?

Comment: You only need to find a counter-example to show that it doesn't hold.

Comment: @Bubububu, can I show a counterexample with $n=2$?

Comment: For generality, you need to show that it doesnt hold for any $p\geq 2$, $\Bbb R^p$. Just consider a simple case, like $(1,0,\dots ,0)$ etc